# Find out in what format is date in using strptime

Tags: python, datetime, type-conversion, strptime

I am having an issue in my python project. I have a date in string format `"2022-12-14T18:25:23.978000+00:00"` and I need to convert it into datetime. I found out strptime method in documentation for that, however I am having trouble actually finding out what format is my string in so can decouple it correctly? Is there some special method that would help me with that?

Comment: Look for ISO 8601. In Python you have `datetime.fromisoformat` method for parsing to datetime dtype.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I parse an ISO 8601-formatted date?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/127803/how-do-i-parse-an-iso-8601-formatted-date)